# Higher temp and lower rack for thicker crust in brownies?

Tags: oven, brownies

I would like to thicken the crust of my brownies. Will I be able to achieve this by setting the pan at a lower level on the oven racks and increasing the temperature? Or do I maintain the same temperature and increase the time? My oven uses a large heating element attached from the top -- that's also where the thermometer hangs.

Presently, the brownies I have are nicely done through and through, but it seems to need a thicker crust. Is this achievable? Or does having a thick crust sacrifice internal doneness due to non-penetration of overhead heat?

Recipe is as follows:

80-g (3/4 cup) pecan halves, roasted and chopped

88g (3 oz) unsweetened chocolate

1 tsp salt

220g (~1/2 lb) unsalted butter

150g (3/4 cup) granulated sugar

100g (1/2 cup) brown sugar

2 large eggs (~110g)

1 1/2 tsp vanilla extract

140g (3/4 cup) All-purpose flour

18 g (1/8 cup) cocoa powder

Deposited in 12-slot pan made for circular cupcakes. 30 mins in a 350F oven with the thermometer hanging directly on the heating element.

Answer (score 2):

Use your normal recipe and then *leave the brownies in the oven with the heat turned off!*

Start with 10 minutes and next time increase the time until you've reached the crust thickness you desire.

**Why?**

Leaving them in the oven with the heat turned off will keep on drying the crust (thus thickening it) until the oven cools down completely. (Don't leave them that long or you'll have a brick instead of brownies)

#### ;-)

Comment: The last time I read that in a recipe was for oven-bake churros -- leave them in the oven. I'll try in my next batch.